# array search won't work with max($array) but works when defined

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays `$yvalues` and `$xyvalues`

**this code returns an empty set for** `$matches`.

```
$a= max($yvalues);// equals 200
function my_search($haystack) {
    global $a;

$needle=$a;

return(strpos($haystack, $needle)); 
} 


$matches = array_filter($xyvalues, 'my_search');
print_r($matches);
```

**This code works**

```
 $a= max($yvalues);// equals 200
function my_search($haystack) {
//      global $a;

$needle='200';

return(strpos($haystack, $needle)); 
} 


$matches = array_filter($xyvalues, 'my_search');
print_r($matches);
```

in my trial code what I have works which is why I'm asking for help.

```
$b= array('11','20','23','14','23');
$c =array('20,12','13,12','200,23','100,23');
$bmax = max($b);
//echo $bmax ."<BR>";
function my_search($haystack) {
    global $bmax;

    $needle =$bmax;

    return(strpos($haystack, $needle)); 
}

$matches = array_filter($c, 'my_search');
print_r($matches);
$tst = key($matches);
```

Comment: `$a` is not defined in global scope.

Comment: What about `xyvalues` vs `yvalues`

Comment: @AbraCadaver first line :-)

Comment: Why not just do it properly, without global variables? That’s what the `use` keyword is for. http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Better show an example before everbody goes nuts here. Inore my first comment. But show examples with expected and current results.

Comment: Also probably want `strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false`

Comment: And use `strpos` save because not found gives real FALSE but found on position 0 is 0 and as we now `0==false` is TRUE! Do `strpos($haystack, $needle)!==false`

Comment: Dang it, I was just about to create an answer bringing the `!==` part up.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions:  In the question yes, in real life no.  It must be in a class method or another function.

Comment: With the last update I added my test code, the expected results are 'code'Array ( [3] => 100,40 )'code'.      I am trying to the the key values from the $xyvalues of every instance that has the max y value.

Comment: Check my answer, but this `Array ( [3] => 100,40 )` breaks fully all logic here.  `max($b);` is `23` and `100,40` isnt in the code? What do you realy do here?

Comment: @AbraCadaver To what points your `question yes, in real life no` message?

Comment: Global var is used right here test this code `$a = 'xyz'; function useglobal() { global $a; print $a; } useglobal();` But NOT in an online tester where its mostly fetched in a local function that creates a local variable or it is done with eval() in the same way. :-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: _first line :-)_

Comment: @AbraCadaver But your first comment is wrong ;-) for real

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you can to this

```
<?php    
#WORKING
$yvalues= array('11','20','23','14','23');
$xyvalues =array('20,12','13,12','200,23','100,23');
global $a;
$a = (string)max($yvalues);// equals 200
function my_search2($haystack) {
    global $a;
    $needle=(string)$a;
    return (bool)(strpos($haystack, $needle)!==false);
}
$matches = array_filter($xyvalues, 'my_search2');
print_r($matches);

#MODERN
print_r(array_filter($xyvalues, function($haystack) use ($yvalues){
    $needle = (string)max($yvalues);
    return (bool)(strpos($haystack, $needle)!==false);    
}));
```

Result: `Array ( [2] => 200,23 [3] => 100,23 )`

Points:

- if you remove `(string)` from the $needle it will not work anymore

> If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character

- if you want to savely generate an global var do `global $a;` first.

:-)